# mysql query group by day on timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id   income created_at
-----------------------
966  300    1516182896
965  -1050  1516188513
964  2000   1516444061
963  600    1513267843
```

I am running the following query to get sum of income per day (the last 10 days):

```
SELECT sum(income) AS income, `created_at`
FROM `incomes`
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY))
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME("created_at"))
```

I just get:

```
income  created_at
-------------------
1850    1516182896
```

it gives the total sum regardless of the date groping with the last created_at.

What am i missing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the string created_at - either remove the quotes or use mysql  escape character (backtick). note the created at will still be indeterminate you maybe should select DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`))

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(income) AS income, DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) as doy
FROM `incomes`
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY))
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
GROUP BY doy;
```

You made an error by grouping by varchar `"created_at"` instead of column `created_at`.

Answer (score 0):

you should add date to select:

```
SELECT sum(income) AS income, `created_at`, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`)) as dd
FROM `incomes`
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY))
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
GROUP BY dd
```

Comment: Note your answer has two errors. You are using varchar `"created_at"` instead of `created_at` column name and selecting `created_at` too that is not in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You are right @marcell, I just copy-pasted that part of SQL